# How add icon to textScrollList

Tags: python, maya

Is posible add icon mesh to textScrollList items in maya python ?

```
def allMeshes(*args):
listMesh = cmd.ls(type="mesh")
geometry = cmd.listRelatives(listMesh, p=True )

if len(geometry) > 0:
    for g in geometry:
        cmd.textScrollList('lstMesh', e=True, a=g) #here add icon
else:
    return
```

Thank you

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it has any way to add icons or images. This can be done using `PySide`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, I don't see a way to add an icon for that control, but here's how you can get it working using `PySide` Maya natively comes with `PySide` so there's no need to install anything. If you're using 2017/2018 then it uses `PySide2` instead and requires very minor changes.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import maya.cmds as cmds


class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Inherit QDialog.
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        # Create a list.
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(parent=self)

        # Create a layout so the list will stretch with the window.
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.list)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Set window properties.
        self.setWindowTitle("My tool")
        self.resize(300, 500)

        # Populate list with all mesh objects.
        self.populate_list()

    def populate_list(self):
        # Collect all meshes in the scene.
        geometry = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type="mesh"), parent=True) or []

        # This uses Maya's internal icons.
        # You can just point it to whatever icon you want.
        img_name = cmds.resourceManager(nameFilter="*mesh*")[0]
        img_path = ":/{}".format(img)

        # Create list items.
        for obj in geometry:
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(obj)
            item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(0, 50)) # Increases item's height a bit.
            item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(img_path))
            self.list.addItem(item)


# Create an instance of the tool.
win = Window()
win.show()
```

Here's the result with 3 spheres in the scene:

[image: List example]

Comment: If that answered your question please accept this answer so the community knows that it has been resolved.